# How can add content line-by-line in ansible?

Tags: ansible

I want to add a few lines in a file as follows

```
*.file_size=100
*.db_size=1234
```

So, I just want the same format of the content added into one file along with that special characters through the ansible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `|` to do the job. `|` will add `\n` at the end of each line. No double quotes are needed here.

```
- name: insert something
  lineinfile: 
    path: /home/aFile
    line: | 
      *.file_size=100
      *.db_size=1234
```

Comment: Thank you @Yi Ren ,  how to add multiple contents at dynmically ?

can you post the answer please too me ?

Comment: @Raghu, What do you mean by adding contents at dynamically?

Comment: Hi @Shubham,

Right now i am giving lines in line argument. So i want to add line while executing the playbook through.

example:

ansible-playbook --extra-vars="hostname= ... line=*.file_size=100 *.file_download=123 like thissss

Comment: Hi  @Yi Ren,

I have one question

Comment: I generated one ssh key in ansible master and i  copied public key in target machine. I am able to connect password less authentication as well as , How to connect some other user without asking password ?

Comment: @Raghu, if you are connected as the root user, you can use become: yes and become_user: <your_user>.

Comment: If generated as a normal user and those ssh key through can connect someone ?.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **blockinfile** ansible module, below is an example for same,

```
- name: insert/update "Match User" configuration block in /etc/ssh/sshd_config
  blockinfile:
    path: /root/a.log
    block: "*.file_size=100 *.db_size=1234"
    marker: ""
```

You can also refer to the documentation [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/blockinfile_module.html).